# window.open on load page (ASP.NET) using Method=POST

Tags: asp.net, javascript, post

i need open pop up in asp.net using post Method and window.open to rezise te new windows.

my code:

Open the pop up:

```
function mdpbch(URL) {
    child = window.open(URL, "passwd","dependent=1,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=475");
    child.location.href = URL;
    if (child.opener == null) {
      child.opener = window;
    }
    child.opener.name = "opener";
  }
```

URL:

```
function PagoEnLinea(Banco)
{
    switch(x){
        case "BCH":
            document.frmEnvia.action = SERV + "/llamacom.asp";
             url = SERV + "lamacom.asp
             alert(url);
             mdpbch(url);
             document.frmEnvia.submit();
            break;
    }    
}
```

ASPX:

```
<body>
    <form id="frmEnvia" runat="server" name="formulario" method="post" target="_blank">

    <div style="visibility:hidden;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtXml" runat="server" Visible="true" />
    </div>
    .....    
</body>
```

on page load (code behind) i create a xml string and put it in the textbox txtXml.

i need use post method becose the server validate te method, and window.open becose need customize the pop up

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should manipulate the object:

```
parentWindow
```

Inside the **document** object; before you submit the form, something like this:

```
switch(x){
    case "BCH":
        document.frmEnvia.action = SERV + "/llamacom.asp";
         url = SERV + "lamacom.asp
         alert(url);
         mdpbch(url);
         //here you manipulate the parentWindow element
         document.parentWindow.scrollbars... (add the attributes you need)
         //--
         document.frmEnvia.submit();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the name of the popup to `passwd`, you should then be able to set the `target` attribute of the form to `passwd`.

So the only change needed is the following:

```
<form ... target="passwd">
```